# SQL query returns unwanted values select count name lastname returns all records

Tags: sql, sql-server

Hello guys I have query which should return values of max count with name and lastname. But it returns all records :

```
Select n.vardas,n.pavarde,MAX(n.cnt) as planu_kiekis
FROM 
(SELECT COUNT(t1.abonentoID) as cnt,t2.vardas,t2.pavarde FROM Abonentas t1
join Asmuo t2 on  t1.asmensID=t2.asmensID
group by t1.asmensID,t2.vardas,t2.pavarde)n
group by n.vardas,n.pavarde
order by planu_kiekis desc
```

table abonentas :

```
  abonentoID--asmensID
1    [1]     --  [1]
2    [2]     --  [1]
3    [3]     --  [1]
4    [4]     --  [1]
5    [5]     --  [2]
6    [6]     --  [2]
7    [7]     --  [3]
8    [8]     --  [3]
9    [9]     --  [3]
10   [10]    --  [3]
```

table asmuo

```
  asmensID--vardas--------pavarde
1  [1]       [toom]      [bulso]
2  [2]       [john]      [trien]
3  [3]       [zack]      [boolshak]
```

Expected result :

```
   vardas -- pavarde -- planukiekis
1   [toom]   [bulso]       [4]
2   [zack]  [boolshack]    [4]
```

result I get :

```
   vardas -- pavarde -- planukiekis
1   [toom]   [bulso]       [4]
2   [zack]  [boolshack]    [4]
3   [john]   [trien]       [2]
```

Comment: Why would you not want the `john trien` record?

Comment: You don't even have a WHERE statement. Getting all results is not unexpected.

Comment: Remove `t1.asmensID` from group by of inner query probably...  you're aggregating on it and summing it.. pick one.  Run `SELECT COUNT(t1.abonentoID) as cnt,t2.vardas,t2.pavarde FROM Abonentas t1
join Asmuo t2 on  t1.asmensID=t2.asmensID
group by t1.asmensID,t2.vardas,t2.pavarde` and you'll see what I mean.

Comment: @DanBracuk becouse I need max values how many abonentasID values asmouID has

Comment: @xQbert it didn't help :/

Comment: add where clause cnt = (select max(cnt) from n)

Comment: @AycanYaşıt I would put WHERE statement but I don't know how to impletment it it throws errors that max(count(t1.abonentoID) invalid.

Comment: @ChintuS it  throws error invalid object n

Comment: @Bensinaspa, ChintuS is correct, the syntax might be off but your query asks for the maximum count of each name you need to specify the value in the where clause.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you want `TOP WITH TIES`:

```
Select TOP (1) WITH TIES n.vardas, n.pavarde, MAX(n.cnt) as planu_kiekis
FROM (SELECT COUNT(t1.abonentoID) as cnt, t2.vardas, t2.pavarde
      FROM Abonentas t1 join
           Asmuo t2
           on t1.asmensID = t2.asmensID
      group by t1.asmensID, t2.vardas, t2.pavarde
     ) n
group by n.vardas, n.pavarde
order by planu_kiekis desc ;
```

Alternatively, you can use `rank()`:

```
Select TOP (1) WITH TIES n.vardas, n.pavarde, MAX(n.cnt) as planu_kiekis
FROM (SELECT COUNT(t1.abonentoID) as cnt, t2.vardas, t2.pavarde,
             RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY t2.vardas, t2.pavarde
                          ORDER BY COUNT(t1.abonentoID) DESC) as seqnum
      FROM Abonentas t1 join
           Asmuo t2
           on t1.asmensID = t2.asmensID
      GROUP BY t1.asmensID, t2.vardas, t2.pavarde
     ) n
WHERE seqnum = 1
order by planu_kiekis desc ;
```

Comment: Oh my god thank you all I needed is top with ties. Code works great!